# Issue with animation and timing and run loops etc

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make elements appear and disappear with fading animation when the user clicks. I have this working but there is a problem if the user clicks twice in quick succession or before an animation has finished.
I know the problem will be related to the run loop and the timing of the events and animation etc., but as a newbie to html/js I'm not experienced enough with these issues in that context to know the best solution.

Here's a fiddle, if you click on the first line and wait a few seconds between each click it'll work, if you click furiously you'll soon start to see problems.

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/mungbeans/wqUgC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a more common issue than you might think. The issue is that you have an event set up to set your element to `display: none`. But if you click again, you want to stop that event from taking place. So what you need to do is keep a reference to the event (`setTimeout()` returns this) so that you can call `clearInterval()` on that reference if you need to cancel the hiding of the element:

```
var listener = (function() {
    var interval = 0; //A variable to retain the interval            

    return function() { //return the original function into listener
        var title = document.getElementById('title');

        //dismiss any plans to hide/show the element because we've changed our minds
        // (if the event already fired, this does nothing, which is fine):
        clearInterval(interval); 

        if (title.dataset.displayed == 'yes') {
            title.dataset.displayed = 'no';
            setTimeout(function () {
            title.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 2.0s ease";
            title.style.opacity = 0.0;
            }, 0);

            //don't forget to hold onto the interval!
            interval = setTimeout(function() { title.style.display = 'none'; }, 2000);
        }
        else {
            title.dataset.displayed = 'yes';
            title.style.display = 'block';

            //It's probably not necessary to retain the interval here. 
            // But it doesn't hurt anything.
            interval = setTimeout(function () {
                title.style.webkitTransition = "opacity 2.0s ease";
                title.style.opacity = 1.0;
            }, 0);
        }
    };
}());


var li = document.getElementById('list');
li.addEventListener("click", listener, false);
```

Note that I wrapped your listener function inside a larger, immediately invoked function expression that returns the original function. I did this so that `interval` is retained from one call of `listener()` to the next. You could also make `interval` a global variable, but those are naughty and this solution is much more pleasantly self-contained.

Seems to work fine when I swap it into your JSFiddle. Good job with the rest of the code!

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would just be to add a simple lock that prevents any additional animations from being fired. I've done so [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wqUgC/2/).

A few notes on the code - 
The animation lock on the code probably shouldn't accessible to other parts of the code, so I put it in a separate context. Also, to ensure that everything is firing at the right time, I added a single integer control, "animate time", to handle the animation rate.